# jQuery mouseleave - mouseenter just work in the First Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, dom-events

I'm struggling trying to set a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event in several videos. Everything seems that work perfectly, the video plays when I `mouseenter` and stop when `mouseleave`.

However, when **I add more than one video**, just play the first video. I am trying to figure out what it's missing what I don't find the way to do it.

Here is the link to codepen: https://codepen.io/felixgonzalo/pen/poJoXRW

My code is:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">

        <div class="video-container">
            <video id="video" class="video" controls class="border" controls="false" muted loop>
                <source src="https://www.errorerror.studio/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/ee.st-honesty-clip-00.mp4" preload="auto" type="video/mp4" autoplay />
            </video>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="video-container">
            <video id="video-2" class="video" controls class="border" controls="false" muted loop>
                <source src="https://www.errorerror.studio/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/ee.st-honesty-clip-00.mp4" preload="auto" type="video/mp4" autoplay />
            </video>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.video').prop('currentTime', 0)

        function Play() {
            $('.video').get(0).play();
        }
        function Stop() {
            $('.video').prop('currentTime', 0).get(0).pause();
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.video-container').mouseenter(function(){
                $('.overlay', this).addClass("hide")
                Play();
            }).mouseleave(function(){
            $('.overlay', this).removeClass("hide")
            Stop();
        });
        });
```

I also tried to make it in JS but didn't work out:

```
        var container = document.querySelector('.video-container');

        container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        this.querySelector('.overlay').classList.remove('hide');
        Stop();
        });

        container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        this.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('hide');
        Play()
        });
```

Really appreciate any help

Comment: I opened the codepen and it works on both elements :|

Comment: Hagai, check this out again, just work the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function play gets only the first video because you specified the `0` index. You need to pass the current video index you're hovering to trigger the playback.
EDIT: Working code.
I made your functions taking an argument, which I'm setting to the first video element children of the element triggering the mouse events.

```
$('.video').prop('currentTime', 0)

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.video-container').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.overlay', this).addClass("hide")
        $(this).children('.video')[0].play();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('.overlay', this).removeClass("hide")
        $($(this).children('.video')[0]).prop('currentTime', 0)
        $(this).children('.video')[0].pause();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond @Raekh . I tryied the code and the console says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).play is not a function", "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pause is not a function"

Comment: I edited it a second time, because I tried to call play on the jQuery variable. It should be ok now. When I copy paste this code into your original codepen it works as expected.

Comment: it just work perfect! however when I apply it in the wp site, it doesnt work, again says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined" -> https://www.errorerror.studio/work/

Comment: You might have a problem with jQuery. Try logging $.